# How to add the previous balance to the current balance using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Php

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        Amount<input type="text" name="edit_amount" id="edit_amount" class="form-control" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)"/>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-2">
        Cash Tendered</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_payment" id="edit_payment" class="form-control"onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)"/>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
       Change </strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_change" id="edit_change"readonly="" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-2">
        Balance</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_balance" id="edit_balance"readonly="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['balance'] ?>" />
        </div>
```

This row balance is the balance of last transaction of patient. This echo balance to see/check the remaining balance of patient.

Javascript

```
$(function() {

    $("#edit_payment").on("keydown keyup", sum);
 function sum() {

    var textValue1 = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('edit_payment').value);
    var textValue2 = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('edit_amount').value);
   if (textValue1>=textValue2) {
    document.getElementById('edit_balance').value = "0"; 
    document.getElementById('edit_change').value = textValue1 - textValue2; 
   }
    else if(textValue1<textValue2){
      document.getElementById('edit_change').value = "0"; 
      document.getElementById('edit_balance').value = textValue2 - textValue1; 

    }
 }

});
```

My Problem is I want if the patient transacts again and the patient will have another balance i want to add the previous balance and the Current Balance.

For Example,

The Patient Has $100 on the previous balance in the last transaction Then the patient will transact again and the total amount of transaction is $200 then the patient pays $50 so that the balance is $150. Then the total balance of that patient is will become $250  because of $100 of the previous then $150 for current..

Comment: Hello, Guys is it possible to do?

Comment: Don't get what you want to do. Please explain calculation logic more specifically.

Comment: @bravemaster The logic is once the patient has previous balance and try to balance again the previous balance and the current balance will be added.

Comment: you're saying deposit, but how come do I see only withdrawals in your code?
all minus signs.

Comment: another example i'm the patient the total amount to my procedure is $100 but i have only $50 so that the balance to my account is $50, So again if i go to another procedure and the total procedure is $200 but i have $100 so that the total balance to my account is $150.

Comment: i don't have code yet for this adding balance, in my code in javascript just simple subtraction to get change

Comment: can you give what is the code for this adding balance sorry i'm just beginner trying to understand about javascript

Comment: But sir @bravemaster did you get my point sir?

Comment: Yes sir just like deposit

Comment: Please tell me what is Amount and Change. I see what is Cash Tendered doing. But I have no idea what others do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209462/discussion-between-johnerick-cuizon-and-bravemaster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in your code:

- `isInputNumber` was bound to `#edit_payment` so the jQuery callback won't work correctly.
- If you want to decrease balance on every `keyup` event, you have to store the first balance(`$row['balance']`) somewhere before event listeners.

```js
const parseNumber = function(value) {
   value = parseFloat(value);
   if (isNaN(value)) {
      value = 0;
   }
   return value;
}
const balanceInput = $("#edit_balance");
const paymentInput = $("#edit_payment");
const balance = parseNumber(balanceInput.val());
$("#edit_payment").on("keyup", function() {
  let tmpBalance = balance;  
  let amount = parseNumber(paymentInput.val());
  if (tmpBalance >= amount) {
     tmpBalance = tmpBalance - amount;
  }
  balanceInput.val(tmpBalance);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
        Amount<input type="text" name="edit_amount" id="edit_amount" class="form-control" />
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-2">
        Cash Tendered</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_payment" id="edit_payment" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
       Change </strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_change" id="edit_change"readonly="" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-2">
        Balance</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_balance" id="edit_balance"readonly="" class="form-control" value="40" />
        </div>
```